# Integrable function and partition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f:[a,b] \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ integrable.

prove that there is a partition $a = \alpha_0 < \alpha_1 < \dots < \alpha_n = b$ of $[a,b]$ and that it is unique, such that for all $j \in \{1, \dots n\}$ one has that,
$$\int_{\alpha_{j-1}}^{\alpha_j} f(x) dx = \frac{1}{n}\int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx$$

I'm having some difficulties to prove it. Anyone can find a good way to solving it?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: it is enough to show that if $f$ is Riemann integrable in $[a,b]$ then the function defined by $g(x):=\int_a^x f(t)\,\mathrm d t$ is continuous and strictly increasing, and so $g([a,b])=[0,g(b)]$.

Comment: Ok. Can you explain what means the last thing you wrote ($g([a,b])=[0,g(b)]$)?

Comment: @ElricEd that the image of $g$ is $[0,g(b)]$

Comment: Ah! I was thinking here, how with this i can get to that result? what others conclusions i can get with this?

Comment: @ElricEd $g$ is continuous and defined on a closed interval, so its image is both connected and compact - meaning that its image is a closed interval. $g$ is increasing, so necessarily the minimum element of $g([a,b])$ is $g(a)$ and the maximum element $g(b)$.

Comment: sorry for not being able to see how the minimum and maximum of g helps me find the partition in which that equality is satisfied...

Comment: could you show me the demonstration you are trying to show me?